# How can I pass a parameter in URL

Tags: laravel

How can I pass a parameter in URL, like .com/numune?numune_id=134&address_town=420&address_city=34, then query DB accordingly and pass it to a view in laravel?

```
Route::get('/model/{id}/numune?numune_id={numune_id}&address_town={address_town}&address_city={address_city}', 'NumuneController@ModelNumuneList')->name('list');
```

Comment: Remove the parameters from your route. Use `$request->input('numune_id')` in your method to access the `numune_id` parameter

Comment: how can i view from db in view

Answer (score 0):

OK, well, there's a few steps to it. Assuming that you will always be passing the ID, town and city in the URL, then you could use the following in your routes file :

```
Route::get('/model/{id}/{town_id}/{city_id}', 'NumuneController@ModelNumuneList')->name('list');
```

Then in your Controller you can access them as follows :

```
public function ModelNumuneList(Request $request) { 
    $entity = Model::where('id', $request->id)->where('town_id', $request->town_id)->where('city_id', $request->city_id)->first();
```

Assuming you match an entity, you can then send the user to the view, along with the entity, as follows :

```
return view('yourview')->with(compact('entity'));
```

At which point you can access your entity in the view using {{ $entity->id }} and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
I will do as you say

Comment: If {city_id} is empty, will I define a separate route in it?

Comment: You would have to define it as an optional parameter.